# Symfony + Doctrine problems with modeling the given database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a database given, which will continually be filled by an automatic import. So I can't change the database structure and have to build the Doctrine model around the database. Therefore, I generated a model for this and the most things work fine in my source code, but especially not for the following tables.

```
Table Device
----------
deviceId (pk)
name
deviceType (fk to DeviceType)
...

Table Processor
-----------
deviceId (pk)
ProcessorName
Clockspeed
...

Table RAM
-----------
deviceId (pk)
Size
Manufacturer
...

Table DeviceType
------------
deviceTypeId(pk)
DeviceType
...
```

Doctrine was generating a one-to-one mapping, for example, between the device and the RAM table, what is wrong I think. 
The problem is, the tables are sharing the primary key (DeviceId). So if the there is a device with ID 1 in the device table, there is also a dataset in the RAM table if the deviceType is 'RAM' (defined in the deviceType table). ID 2 is, for example a Processor, so there is an entry in device and in Processor, both with id 2. And so on ... a dataset entry in the device table always have a deviceType, defined in the deviceType Table.

I am not the database specialist, but isn't that actually an is-a-relation and not a one to one mapping? How can I map the subtypes of device (RAM, Processor) proper to the parent table in Doctrine?

After googling, I think a single table inheritance is what I am searching for, but I don't know if Doctrine can handle my database model proper, because the only thing the Subtypes (RAM, Processor ...) sharing with the parent class (device) is the id field. All other fields are quite different for each table.

It is really important, that Doctrine will not touch the structure of my database, because the import will not work anymore.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out, that the Simple Derived Identity use case from http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html will probably fit to me. Let me stick to the example on the page: The direction from the example User class to the address class is pretty simple. But if i want to achieve the reverse side (get the address from the user) i supposed to add simply the field "address" to the user class. But if i do that, doctrine wants to add a foreign key to my user class. That will change the database model, what i dont want. In my real database there is no foreign key from the parent class (Device) to the child class (e.g. Processor).

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not think it is possible without changing the existing database due to its  "bad design". If you can not update the import process matching a slightly changed schema, try using the auto generated mapping and implement the needed functions to retrieve the objects in a custom repository.

Comment: Ok, i gave it a try and tried to update the doctrine model, now i get integrity violations if doctrine set a new foreign key ...